# Android AES file encryption failing sometimes

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, padding

I have been trying to encrypt some XML files in android with AES, send them using FTP to a server, and then unencrypt them in a Linux terminal using java.

I tried encrypting with AES, DES, Triple DES and other encryption methods, but after sending the files to the server by FTP, some of them (about 25%) can't get decrypted, always the same ones.
I also tried to unencrypt the received files inside an android emulator, but it didn't work either

Tried also to download the spongycastle jars and use them instead of the BouncyCastle libraries, which I read somewhere to be outdated in android java, but it didn't work either.

I also tried removing every \r\n before encrypting the files.

The libraries I'm working with now are these:

[EncodeDecodeAES.java](https://code.google.com/p/oobd/source/browse/trunk/clients/skds/base_src/org/oobd/crypt/AES/EncodeDecodeAES.java)

The error I'm getting now is "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption"

The code I'm currently using for encrypting / decrypting is:

```
String fileNotEncrypted=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "unencrypted.xml";
RandomAccessFile fileNotEncryptedRa = new RandomAccessFile(fileNotEncrypted, "r");
byte[] textNotEncryptedByte = new byte[(int)fileNotEncryptedRa.length()];
fileNotEncryptedRa.read(textNotEncryptedByte);

Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
byte[] textEncryptedByte = EncodeDecodeAES.encryptBytes("1234567890123456", textNotEncryptedByte);      

String fileEncrypted=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "encrypted.xml";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileEncrypted);
fos.write(textEncryptedByte);
fos.close();
```

And this is the code i'm using for decrypting the files I receive by FTP

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);

//encryptedFile is a String I get from main(String[] args), so I can use the code in a script easily
RandomAccessFile fileEncrypted = new RandomAccessFile(encryptedFile, "r");
byte[] textEncryptedByte = new byte[(int)fileEncrypted.length()];
fileEncrypted.read(textEncryptedByte);

byte[] textDecryptedByte = EncodeDecodeAES.decryptBytes("Dephi20101234567", textEncryptedByte);

//decriptedFile is another String got from main(String[] args)
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile);
fos.write(textDecryptedByte);
fos.close();
```

Solution:

The problem was caused by trying to send the ciphertext by FTP.
What I had to do was encoding the ciphertext into base64, then writing the base64 into a file, and sending that file by FTP.

For Base64 encoding I'm using the open source libraries found here:
[Base64Coder](http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/)

Comment: It's a little unclear, but the problem appears to be with your ciphertext. However, it sounds like you have been focused on your plaintext, are you encoding your ciphertext? Is your ftp transfer reliable?

Comment: I tried resending the files by ftp in case it was some problem with the transmission, but the ones that failed in the first transmission kept failing, in exactly the same point. I place the cyphertext directly into the file, with the FileOutputStream, then don't touch it again until trying to decrypt it. I will edit the post and add the code I'm using for decryption, just in case.

Comment: Ftp protocol does have encoding, and encoding issues can cause problems like this, you might want to try and base64 encode the ciphertext for transfer.

Comment: You do know that `RandomAccessFile.read` needs to happen in a loop? Until it returns -1 ?

Comment: I'm using RandomAccessFile.read just on the last 2 tests (have done 21 by now), and had the same problem before. But have been using ftp since the beginning, so the idea of base64 encoding the ciphertext is a good one. I'm going to give it a try and post the results. I thought using ftp to transfer a file would produce a bit by bit perfect copy of the file in the server...

Comment: Binary mode ftp does bit by bit copy. Not so much for text transfer. Note that you should check that the full file was transerred. The new (1.7) Java NIO libraries contain convenience methods for reading a complete file to String or byte[]...useful for testing on Java SE.

Comment: In the end, it was FTP transmission that was breaking my ciphertext. Thanks a lot to jbtule. Now I just encode the ciphertext into base64 before writing it to the file to be sent, and reverse the process in the server. How I mark the question as answered? It was my first question in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a very similar problem about Base64 class of android while decrypting a file encrypted on Linux (or vice versa). Linux was using `\n` only (or `\r` only, don't remember) instead of `\r\n` in progress. This was causing files to have different lengths and fail decryption. Above, you stated that all `\r\n` was removed but I guess you did not check for `\n`. Try to check for both case which should be coherent.

At last, http://examples.oreilly.com/9781565924024/files/oreilly/jonathan/util/Base64.java  is the Base64 class which I used both on android and Linux in order to ensure coherency.

Comment: You're right, I didn't check for \n. I will try that too and see if it works. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: In the end, the \n \r and \n\r weren't giving me any trouble. I checked the new method inserting on purpose some linux and windows carriage returns, and they get encrypted / decrypted correctly. Thanks for the idea, anyways :)